# 'Saw your speech' or 'heard your speech'?

Tags: word-choice

If I have just watched a speech, what is the most appropriate way of conveying this to the speaker? *I just **saw** your speech*, or *I just **heard** your speech*.

Comment: What makes you think only one is ‘correct’? There is more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Maybe 'correct' wasn't the right word to phrase the sentence. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  And I would condemn all of them.  :)

Answer (score 4):

"I just saw your speech" is a perfectly valid way to refer to watching a video of a speech.

Answer (score 0):

You could say "I just watched a video of your speech" which might be clearer.